# Angular 5 add error message

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this code in my view:

```
<div layout-gt-xs="row">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput #inputstate class="form-control" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="data.account.username"
             name="username" required>
      <mat-error *ngIf="formControl.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I have the request to server where I have custom validator. For some cases, I have error response and I should show error message. The issue is that this error message is not displayed on UI. The code for defining form control:

```
formControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required
]);
```

The code related to adding errors to form control:

```
stopEdit(): void {
this.userService.update(this.data).subscribe(
  data => console.log("data"),
  error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.formControl.setErrors({'username': true});
    this.formControl.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
);
}
```

By debug, I checked that status in form control is invalid. But getErrorMessage() method is not executed. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of getErrorMessage(), try with properties. It will dynamically update the DOM.

Comment: You have a form control, but not using it in the form actually, makes no sense? :D